# ImageVIew background set as black in some devices in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, imageview, android-imageview

I tried to rotate the image by using matrix values and set the rotated bitmap to the image view. In this case, the image view background is set as black. Please provide any suggestions on this.

Device details: Motorola Moto G(4) (Android 7.0 - Api 24)

Sample:

My code:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.LayoutParameters = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 1200);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.Nature);
        linearLayout.AddView(imageView);
        linearLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.Text = "Click me";
        button.Click += Button_Click;
        button.LayoutParameters = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        linearLayout.AddView(button);
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        SetContentView(linearLayout);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int angle = 45;
        Matrix = new Matrix();
        int cx = bitmap.Width / 2;
        int cy = bitmap.Height / 2;
        this.Matrix.PreTranslate(-cx, -cy);
        this.Matrix.PostRotate(angle);
        this.Matrix.PostTranslate(this.imageView.Width / 2, this.imageView.Height / 2);
        using (var tiltBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, Matrix, false))
        {
         
            imageView.SetImageBitmap(tiltBitmap);
        }
        this.Matrix.Dispose();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want a black background or no background?

Comment: I don't want the background

Comment: Did you try rotating ImageView instead of re-createbitmap ?

Comment: No, my requirement is to rotate the bitmap only.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue with your codes,what version of your device ?